# Making the player to double-jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to allow the player to double-jump,but the player can keep jumping infinitely,can anyone help me? I use Unity 5

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpHeight;
    private bool grounded;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private int jumpCount = 0;
    private int maxJumps = 2;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && jumpCount < maxJumps) {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
            rb.velocity = new Vector2 (rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
            jumpCount = jumpCount + 1;
        }

        if (grounded == true) {
            jumpCount = 0;
        } 

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2 (moveSpeed,rb.velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2 (-moveSpeed,rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collider){
        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            grounded = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is not working, is your character only jumping once, is he never jumping, are you getting an error... And move your code from `Update` to `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: he is jumping only once

Comment: which piece of code should i move to fixedupdate?

Comment: Just change `Update` for `FixedUpdate` it's better when dealing with `Rigidbody`

Comment: the player is still jumping only once

Comment: wait I changed collision to collision2d but the player now can jump infinitely.

Comment: Are you using 2D colliders or regular colliders?

Comment: it was a regular one,but i changed it to 2D ,but now it can jump infinitely

Comment: I mean on your player is the collider you attached on it a 2D collider?

Comment: yes,its a circle collider 2D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can keep jumping infinitely is because you never set `grounded` to `false` so it will always reset the value of your `jumpCount` back to 0 here

```
if (grounded == true) {
    jumpCount = 0;
}
```

So when you jump set `grounded = false` because you're no longer on the ground.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && jumpCount < maxJumps) {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    rb.velocity = new Vector2 (rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
    jumpCount = jumpCount + 1;

    grounded = false;
}
```

And when working with `RigidBody` and physics it's better to use [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)

> FixedUpdate should be used instead of Update when dealing with Rigidbody.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @MightyElf Happy I could help :)